# Spring Data MongoDB - Returning only one element from a nested array using @Query or MongoTemplate and $elemMatch

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

My model consists of a collection of (car) models with a nested collection of fuel types available ("Diesel", "Gasoline", "Hybrid"). Every fuel has another nested collection of doors available.

For instance:

```
{ _id : 'Ford Focus' , fuels : [ {_id : "Diesel" : "doors" : [2 , 3]} , {_id: "Gasoline" , doors :  [2, 3, 4, 5] } ] }
```

If I want to get the doors available for a certain model and fuel type, I can execute:

```
db.models.find( {"_id" : "Ford Focus" , "fuels._id" : "Diesel"}  , { 'fuels' : {$elemMatch: {_id: "Diesel"}  } })
```

How can I translate that to a @Query method in a Spring Data Repository?

```
@Query(value="{ 'id' : ?0 , 'fuel' : ?1 }")
public Model findDoors(Integer model, String fuel);
```

The implementation above, returns a document with a nested array including ALL types of fuels, not only the one passed as parameter. Where can I put the $elemMatch projection in a Spring Data Repository?

**UPDATE**: After some research I tried to acomplish it using a custom repository, the MongoTemplate and the BasicQuery class, following this [post](http://ufasoli.blogspot.com.es/2013/08/mongodb-spring-data-elemmatch-in-field.html)

```
public Model findDoors(Integer model, String fuel){
     Criteria findModelCriteria = Criteria.where("id").is(model);
     Criteria findFuelCriteria = Criteria.where("fuels").elemMatch(Criteria.where("id").is(fuel));
     BasicQuery basicQuery = new BasicQuery(findModelCriteria.getCriteriaObject(), findFuelCriteria.getCriteriaObject());

     return mongoTemplate.findOne(basicQuery, Model.class);
}
```

In this case, I get an exception when the constructor of `PropertyPath` is called, as it is trying to access a field called $elemMatch in Model.class (???)

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException.detectPotentialMatches(PropertyReferenceException.java:134)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException.<init>(PropertyReferenceException.java:59)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:75)
```

Comment: which version of spring-framework are you using? The Spring Data Golsing release requires at least `spring 4.1.7` or better.

Comment: Hi Christoph, I was using Spring 4.1.6.RELEASE, I just tested after upgrading it and it works perfectly, thank you!!